# Get position of item in rdf type sequence with sparql

Tags: sequence, rdf, sparql

i have a sequence encoded like this in rdf:

```
_:blanknode <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type> <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#Seq>.
_:blanknode <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#_0> uri:a.
_:blanknode <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#_1> uri:b.
_:blanknode <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#_2> uri:c.
```

now i want to have the position of a given uri within this list.
is there something like:

```
SELECT ?position
WHERE {
_:blanknode <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type> <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#Seq>.
uri:a <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#_?position> _:blanknode
}
```

---

As a workaround i think i could use:

```
<http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#_0> uri:value "1".
<http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#_1> uri:value "2".
and so on...
```

with the query:

```
SELECT ?position
WHERE {
_:blanknode <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type> <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#Seq>.
uri:a ?seqUri _:blanknode.
?seqUri uri:value ?position
}
```

but there has to be a more elegant way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this using a `REPLACE` function to remove the namespace part of the URI, and then casting the result to an integer, like so:

```
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX uri: <http://example.org/> 

SELECT (xsd:integer(REPLACE(str(?prop), 
           "http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#_", "")) as ?pos)
WHERE { [] a rdf:Seq; 
           ?prop uri:a . 
}
```

Result:

```
pos
---
0
```